# Version error trying to use custom scenario from GitHub

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am taking this one straight from the repo.

I am using this scenario [Azure Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/phone-number-username-passwordless) and when I try to upload the base I get the following error (cut for brevity):

> The specified page contract 'urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp' has invalid version '2.0.0'. The available versions are: '["1.0.0","1.1.0","1.2.0"]'.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current available versions for page layout are `["1.0.0","1.1.0","1.2.0"]`. You can find the version change log [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#version-change-log).

[image]

Try to change the version from `2.0.0` to the available version in `PasswordlessEmailAndPhoneBase.xml` file.

Comment: Yeah I tried that before you replied and it worked. I will do a PR against the Git repo as their Git repo has this error